# Amazon Connect Service Domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-connect, aws-sso

Does anyone know if there is a way to share the domain of Amazon Connect with your Amazon SSO domain (used for Control Tower)?

They both have the same TLD, and seem to have different paths to the actual applications, but I don't see a way to connect the two.

Control Tower sets up SSO and you can set the domain to `<sub-domain>.awsapps.com`. Then your landing page is `<sub-domain>.awsapps.com/start.`

For Connect you can enter a domain, but it can't be one that's used.

Comment: Custom domain should be one of those you own.

Comment: That's not how it works. I choose the `<sub-domain>` when I create my SSO. For example, say I choose `my-company` for my SSO. When I try to create the same on Connect it doesn't allow me to choose `my-company` because it's already in use.

Comment: Also we cannot share TLD of two different aws services

Comment: You don't get the option of a TLD. My hope was that I could use the same sub-domain across apps, since it's the same pool of users. It seems that the only way to do this is to use the SAML integration.